# Total del monto no coincide con el total de cuotas en JAVA

Tags: java

tengo la siguiente incógnita al momento de generar cuotas con un procedimiento que he creado.

```
private void generarCuotas(Double monto, Double cantidad, Date primerVencimiento ){
    Double montoCuotas = monto/cantidad;
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaCuotas.getModel();
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendario.setTime(primerVencimiento);
        calendario.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        Object[] fila = new Object[3];
        fila[0] = i+1;
        fila[1] = formatoFecha.format(calendario.getTime());
        fila[2] = montoCuotas;
        modelo.addRow(fila);
        primerVencimiento = calendario.getTime();
    }
}
```

Lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer los calculos, ejemplo: si el monto es de 1.000.000 y lo divido en 10 partes serian 10 cuotas de 100.000, si sumamos el total de las cuotas da como resultado 1.000.000.
Pero si el monto de la cuota es 1.000.000 y lo divido en 3 partes serian de 333.333,333 si sumamos el total de las cuotas da como resultado 999.999,999, teniendo una diferencia de 1 en el valor total.

¿Como podría agregar esta diferencia a la ultima cuota generada?

Comment: Lo primero es que 1.000.000 / 3 = 333.333,3333333 (período 3). Lo segundo es que esto es un problema de redondeo el cual se debe manejar de acuerdo a las políticas económicas/financieras de la empresa: quizá una de las 3 cuotas obtenga 333.333,334 y listo!

Comment: @E.Betanzos es lo que estoy buscando. En mi caso, necesito agregarle a la ultima cuota esa diferencia.

Comment: En tu caso debes tener una política para tratar estos problemas y cualquier otro que implique redondeo. Lo que te comenté fue solo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Esto sucede porque estas utilizando `Double`. Intenta utilizando [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) para cálculos financieros.

Lo que sucede aquí al usar `Double` es que hay un error de precisión ya que la base de este tipo de datos es 2. En cambio, `BigDecimal` realiza los cálculos en base 10.

[Aqui está la explicación](https://www.javamexico.org/blogs/luxspes/por_que_usar_bigdecimal_y_no_double_para_calculos_aritmeticos_financieros) mas detallada de por qué utilizar BigDecimal en vez de Double o Float.

Comment: Este problema en específico no tiene nada que ver con la precisión del `double` ya que esa división en base 10 no es exacta. El problema aquí está en cómo manejar los redondeos.

Comment: @E.Betanzos exactamente

Answer (score 0):

Depende de como quieras redondear,
Puedes restar tu valor total, con el valor total de las cuotas en caso de que estos no te den igual y esa diferencia se la puedes agregar a la ultima o primera cuota, o dependiendo de tus condiciones de negocio.